# how to render Header conditionally based on global state context in next app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Next app and I used Context to handle some loading state. when app start for the first time some loading animations show up and then the corresponding value which is "Isloading" will be false when starting animation finish. I used react Context. my problem is that when I log the value of "isLoading" after loading finished, it gives me "true" while logging it inside other pages give me the correct updated value which is "false". this will cause my header always be displayed. am I doing something wrong?

here is my  _app.tsx:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const loadingCtx = useContext(LoadingContext);
  console.log(loadingCtx.isLoading); // why this line gives me true while it's actually false and in every other pages it gives me false.
  return (
    <LoadingProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {!loadingCtx.isLoading && <Header />}// here I want to load header
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        {!loadingCtx.isLoading && <Footer />}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </LoadingProvider>
  );
}
```

and this is my index.tsx:

```
export default function Home() {
  const loadingCtx = useContext(LoadingContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingCtx.isLoading) {
      loadingCtx.finishLoading(); // this sets isLoading to false after 4 seconds.
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(loadingCtx.isLoading); // I log this line in other pages and they also gives me the correct value which is false.

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        {loadingCtx.isLoading && <AnimatedLogo />}
        {!loadingCtx.isLoading && <Layout />}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the Context:

```
type contextType = { isLoading: boolean; finishLoading: () => void };

const LoadingContext = React.createContext<contextType>({
  isLoading: true,
  finishLoading: () => {},
});

interface LoadingProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const LoadingProvider = ({ children }: LoadingProviderProps) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const finishLoading = () => {
    if (loading === true) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 4000);
    }
  };

  return (
    <LoadingContext.Provider
      value={{ isLoading: loading, finishLoading: finishLoading }}
    >
      {children}
    </LoadingContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default LoadingContext;
```

Comment: I assume isLoading is being stored in state. If so then you should know that state is updated asynchronously meaning that the update will not happen immediately.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that starting animation ends and isLoading updates to false I log it in each page and also inside _app.tsx.for example when I click a link to change route It prints true because _app is rendering first and then it print false inside that specific route page.

Comment: if you want an accurate answer, consider sharing the code of the context. But my guess is that you are storing isLoading inside useState.

Comment: @HasanAga I added the code for context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is due to your `useContext` call. In the App Component the context value is not accessible (it returns undefined). in another word, your data will be accessed in all App children, not itself.

One solution is to call `useContext` inside the `Header` and `Footer` components and based on your context value decide on the return value

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the context outside of the provider so you will always get the default value.

Your `App` component is not wrapped in `LoadingProvider`.
One solution is to move the logic into `<Header/>` so it checks if `isLoading` is `true` and returns accordingly.

Comment: app is wrapped by LoadingProvider and also it doesn't matter if I log inside LoadingProvider or outside it. as long as I do this in _app.tsx the result in same and always true

Comment: Then why do you have another LoadingProvider inside the App component?